# ring size three transactions in txpool after v6 fork

Tags: txpool, orphaned-block

There have been 3 transactions sitting in the [txpool](https://xmrchain.net/txpool) since the beginning of the v6 fork activation about 97 hours ago. Each of these 3 transactions (examples [1](https://xmrchain.net/tx/9e6eaa6957e5a144208b64c133052c88d71f7b45b23cbcd6d5d4c176f4c0ad6d), [2](https://xmrchain.net/tx/fe70cbac14a42069c346350f0c577120ebc81ac5e8185376eedbbed3569512bd), and [3](https://xmrchain.net/tx/09e153055260108a614c53a136e8ac20c9dc563e724523d2cad0eca0de37d1e7)) has a ring size of 3 which is now [invalid after the v6 fork](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/5973/187). According to [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3335/187):

> Transactions drop from the txpool:
>
> - after 7 days if they were included in a block that was orphaned
> - after 24 hours otherwise
>
> The orphaned block case can happen with invalid transactions, if they were mined by a daemon which does not obey consensus (maybe an old one).

More than 24 hours have passed since v6 and the above transactions are still in the tx pool. Should we assume they were included in a block that was orphaned and will disapear in 7 days?

Comment: 131 hours and they are still in mempool: [9e6e...](https://xmrchain.net/tx/9e6eaa6957e5a144208b64c133052c88d71f7b45b23cbcd6d5d4c176f4c0ad6d), [fe70...](https://xmrchain.net/tx/fe70cbac14a42069c346350f0c577120ebc81ac5e8185376eedbbed3569512bd), and [09e1...](https://xmrchain.net/tx/09e153055260108a614c53a136e8ac20c9dc563e724523d2cad0eca0de37d1e7).

Comment: They are still in the tx pool today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, these transactions are no longer appearing in the mempool or anywhere else in the block explorer. Thus, they were dropped.